Header with a logo.img and a navbar section
I running into issues with creating my header section for the FreeCodeCamp product landing page project. I want to have the logo-img to be on the left side of the website and the navbar links to be evenly space between each other in a row on the right side of the website.
I tried fixing this issue by creating a flex box and etc. but can't seem to get what I want. I was wondering if someone with more experience can help me out by explaining what I am doing wrong with my code.


:root {
  --light-pink: #f2e3e6;
  --mild-pink: #ed83b5;
  --dark-pink: #ec297b;
  --yellow: #fff486;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--mild-pink);
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: var(--light-pink);
  border-bottom: 5px solid var(--yellow);
  width: 100%;
}

#nav-bar {
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  color: var(--dark-pink);
  font-family: "League Spartan", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
}

#nav-bar li {
  list-style: none;
}

#nav-bar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: large;
  transition: text-indent .3s ease-in-out;
}
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header id="header">
  <img src="./images/rebel01.png" alt="Rebel Streetwear clothing logo" class="logo" id="header-img" loading="lazy" width="200" />
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-link">
        <a href="#about-us"></a>About us</li>
      <li class="nav-link">
        <a href="#contact-us"></a>Contact us</li>
      <li class="nav-link">
        <a href="#collections"></a>Collections</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main class="homepage">
  <section class="hero-section"></section>
  <section class="main-content"></section>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</main>




See below. I've documented everything in the CSS code.


:root {
  --light-pink: #f2e3e6;
  --mild-pink: #ed83b5;
  --dark-pink: #ec297b;
  --yellow: #fff486;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--mild-pink);
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  /* justify-content: space-around; REMOVED */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: var(--light-pink);
  border-bottom: 5px solid var(--yellow);
  /* width: 100%; CHANGED */
  width: 100vw;
}

#nav-bar {
  /* align-items: end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row-reverse; REMOVED */
  color: var(--dark-pink);
  font-family: "League Spartan", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  /* ADDED */
  width: 100%;
}

/* ADDED */
#nav-bar ul {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}

#nav-bar li {
  list-style: none;
}

#nav-bar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: large;
  transition: text-indent .3s ease-in-out;
}
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=League+Spartan:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header id="header">
  <img src="./images/rebel01.png" alt="Rebel Streetwear clothing logo" class="logo" id="header-img" loading="lazy" width="200" />
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-link">
        <a href="#about-us"></a>About us</li>
      <li class="nav-link">
        <a href="#contact-us"></a>Contact us</li>
      <li class="nav-link">
        <a href="#collections"></a>Collections</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main class="homepage">
  <section class="hero-section"></section>
  <section class="main-content"></section>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</main>



